# ReactJS - Custom Dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I have a drop down that has a nested ul in ECMAScript 6.

**Relevant code for dropdown:**

```
 ......
   handleItemClicked(item){
     alert(item)
  }

   render(){
     return(
              ....
            <UnorderedList whenItemClicked={this.handleItemClicked} />
              ....
    )
}
```

**Relevant code for unordered list:**

```
    return(
        <ul>
           ....
            {this.props.dropItems.map(function(item){
                return (<li onClick={this.props.whenItemClicked(item)} key={item}><a>{item}</a></li>)
            }, this)}
        </ul>
    )
```

**Result:**

There are no errors, however, when the page is loaded the alert event starts immediately and loops for each item in the array. And clicking on a < li > afterwards **DOES NOT** produce an alert event.

What I want is for the alert to occur, not on page load, but as each respective < li > is clicked and only for the item's name, not the names in the entire array.

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks crob, solution:

```
  return (<li onClick={this.props.whenItemClicked.bind(this, item)} style={listItemStyle} key={item}><a>{item}</a></li>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `onClick={this.props.whenItemClicked(item)}`, which is setting onclick to what is evaluated by the function `whenItemClicked`, not the actual function. This is what is causing the alerts.

To get around this, you could bind the function call to the item.

`onClick={this.props.whenItemClicked.bind(this, item)}`

But, perhaps a better solution would be to make a new component to represent the list item, and pass the whenItemClicked function through to that.

```
ListItem = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
      this.props.onClick(this.props.item);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <li onClick={this.handleClick}>{item}</li>;
  }
})
```

Then your map would look like

`return <ListItem onClick={this.props.whenItemClicked} item={item} />`